# How to create an update function on nodejs/mongodb?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I am currently new to nodejs and mongodb what I want to do is make a function to update my win,lose,draw record from my userschema.

My Schema:

```
UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:'string',
    password:'string',
    email:'string',
    //Change Made
    win:{ type: Number, default: 0 },
    lose:{ type: Number, default: 0 },
    draw:{ type: Number, default: 0 }
});
```

My Function for updating:

```
//Update scores
app.post("/user/updateScores", function (req, res) {
    var user = new User({
        username:req.body.username,
        win:req.body.win,
        lose:req.body.lose,
        draw:req.body.draw  
    });

    Users.findOne({ username : req.params.username }, function(error, user) {
    if (error || !user) {
      res.send({ error: error });
    } else {
       user.update(function (err, user) {
       if (err) res.json(err)
        req.session.loggedIn = true;
        res.redirect('/user/' + user.username);
        });
    }
    });
});
```

The problem is when I try updating, when I try updating via my html file. It does not update anything and just stays the same (the values win,lose,draw the default value is 0 so when I logout and login again the values of the win,lose,draw record is still zero). I thoroughly checked if the problem was the html and javascript functions that I have made but this is not the case so I think that the problem is the update function I have made. Any of you guys have an idea where I went wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `post` is being called correctly from the client, you'll need to be careful about variable and parameter names, as the scope right now is that you're saving an exact duplicate of the user object that was just fetched via `findOne`.

You had user declared as a variable of the `post` callback, and then again within the `findOne`. The inner variable `user` will take precedence.

```
app.post("/user/updateScores", function (req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;

    Users.findOne({ username : username }, function(error, user) {
        if (error || !user) {
          res.send({ error: error });          
        } else {
           // update the user object found using findOne
           user.win = req.body.win;
           user.lose = req.body.lose;
           user.draw = req.body.draw;
           // now update it in MongoDB
           user.update(function (err, user) {
               if (err) res.json(err) {
                   req.session.loggedIn = true;
               }
               res.redirect('/user/' + user.username);
           });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: that is another problem. I cannot call properly this function from my html file: the code I use in my home.js is   <form action="/user/updateScores" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
   <input type="text" id="new_user" name="user" value="<%= user.username %>">
   <input type="hidden" id="new_win" name="win" value ="">
   <input type="hidden" id="new_lose" name="lose" value ="">
   <input type="hidden" id="new_draw" name="draw" value ="">
   <input type="button" name="btn" onclick = "save()" value="Save Scores" />
  </form>

Comment: Sorry, but to tack on a new problem in a comment really isn't good etiquette on StackOverflow. It looks like maybe you're not submitting the form data? You've got a button, but it's not a submit button.

Comment: Got it to working now, calling the function but after calling the function I get an error saying ReferenceError: Users is not defined at app.get.req.session.loggedIn. but I already did in my schema and my form right? –

Comment: You keep changing the question.